# Multiplying Columns by A Number in R using Tidy Approach

Tags: r, tidy

Now that funs is "softly depreciated", I can't figure out this simple task: how would you multiply a range of columns by a constant ?!! In other words, how would you rewrite this using Tidy/DPLYR:

data10x <- mtcars%>% 
mutate_at(vars(mpg:hp),funs(.*10))

I tried 
data10x <- mtcars %>% 
mutate_at(vars(mpg:hp),~(.*10))

but it gives me an error.

I must be losing my mind, but this has to be simple! Thank you!

Comment: It is working fine for me Please show your dplyr package version

Comment: also: show your error message?

Comment: It works now, weird!

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine

```
 library(dplyr)
 mtcars %>%
      mutate_at(vars(mpg:hp), ~ . * 10)
```

Or with `across`

```
mtcars %>%
     mutate(across(mpg:hp, ~ .* 10))
```